# IntelliJ: After hiding my "Output" sub-panel within the "Debug" panel, how do I get it back?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 9.0.1.  I have the "Debug" panel open.  I previously had an "Output" sub-panel within the Debug panel showing the System.out text output of my program.  I clicked on the  ->|  button to hide it, and now I can't get it back.   I notice that with the Variables and Watches sub-panels, when I hide them I get an icon on the far right of the Debug toolbar.  But I have no icon for the Output panel.  I've tried restarting IntelliJ but it doesn't help, nor does closing and reopening the Debug panel.

How can I get my "Output" sub-panel back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discovered I could get it back by clicking on a certain spot in the far right of the "Debug" panel toolbar.  It looks like 9.0.1 has a blank icon for the "Output" sub-panel, so you just have to guess where the blank icon is situated and click there.

Comment: thanks Tim Cooper... i used same workaround as above...
i also saw blank icon. and clicked on it to enable

Answer (score 10):

First of all, update to 9.0.3 release, it's free. Then use the Restore Layout button on the left of the Debugger panel.