# For intelliJ 12.X how do i get the console back in the debugger?

Tags: intellij-idea

Just like this question here:

[IntelliJ: After hiding my "Output" sub-panel within the "Debug" panel, how do I get it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3522031/1061426)

I canno get the log/console viewer back in debug mode.

The suggested solution in the given question no longer works the "restore layout" button does nothing, and the "certain spot" on the debug is extremely vague at best.

Is there a way to retrieve the console if it gets vanished (or better yet, just stop that button for vanishing it from even existing)?

Comment: Restore layout should work. If it doesn't work, it's a bug that should be [reported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) and  `.idea/workspace.xml` file from the project attached. Deleting this workspace file should restore the default layout, but your user specific settings for this project will be also lost.

Comment: I've just tried this in 12 and restore works fine for me, along with the other solution I've posted below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am using IntelliJ 12 Ultimate. If the **restore layout** didn't work for you either, this should fix the problem:

1. Open the **Debug** panel.
2. Keep mouse on the **Debug** tab and move it straight right to the **Watches** icon.
3. You may see a few more more icons here, and **Output** may or may not be visible (not visible for me)
4. If visible, click it and the **Output** view will be restored.
5. If not visible, move your mouse slowly to either side of the **Watches** icon and an empty block would highlight indicating that you are hovering over an icon. There may be several of these. Use tooltip to figure out which is **Ouput** and click it.

Worked for me, I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 10):

click the button on the left of Debug View called "restore layout",then the console will go back in the Debug View!  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTIpQ.png)

Answer (score 4):

Syed [explained it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23213099/537554) pretty well, but a picture could be even better:

[image: restore a hidden view]

A view can be hidden via its context menu, then restored by clicking the corresponding icon (*with red circle*) to the right.

Comment: Not seeing that option. Only have the three to the right of this option.

Answer (score 3):

You can restore the layout using this button as of 2018.1.8

[image: Restore Layout]

Answer (score 2):

In 2016.2, I had to re-run in debug mode for it to reappear. I could not find a way to un-hide the console in the debug window.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of IntelliJ you're using, but I've just tried this in version 12 and the console window minimises to the far right of the debugger tabs. Look at where it says 'Debugger' and then eyes right until you see one or more icons over the Watches panel. Try clicking on them. If you're not using version 12, then only god can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In v. 2020.1 there is Layout Settings on the top right corner of Debug window
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've just spent an hour trying to get my console output back, and although this answer didn't solve it, it did help.

I'm on Intellij 11.1 Ultimate Edition, and Restore layout didn't help.  Nor did I have any icons above the Watches window in the debugger, but I clicked around above the Watches anyway - and suddenly my console output was restored.

I've tried clicking around there again to see if I can provide more concrete steps, but without success.  Can only suggest you keep clicking till it reappears.

Comment: This is not really an answer to this question. If you have a question of your own you should ask it separately.

Comment: @KeithSmiley i think it is a comment that got lost!